# Count foreignkey objects in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-database

suppose

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,...)
    ...

class Sold(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(post,...)
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User,...)
```

Now how do i get no of items sold using User model
Something like `User.objects.all().annotate(nbuy=Count("?"))`

Putting "sold" at place of "?" gives number of items user have bought.
What should i do to get no of items user have sold?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it if you query the Sold model like so:

```py
Sold.objects.values('buyer').annotate(nbuy=Count('buyer'))

# returns -> {'buyer': 1, 'nbuy': 23}
```

This returns the the user id and the number of Sale objects that exist with that user id.

Comment: Can it be done in this way ```User.objects.values ...``` ?

Answer (score 0):

Technically `User.objects.all().annotate(nbuy=Count("sold"))` counts all the `Sold` objects linked to a user by a ForeignKey. If I understand your model correctly the link represents the buyer, so you get number of products a user has bought.

I suppose the `user` in your `Product`represents the user offering, i.e. selling the product, so `User.objects.all().(nsold=Count("product"))` would give you that number.

Comment: Cannot resolve keyword 'product' into field

Comment: Strange, using your models it works on my machine

Comment: What are the allowed field choices (in the last line of the stack trace)?

Comment: i think you have misssed something here ```User.objects.all().(nsold=Count("product"))```